# Is there a metric on $\mathbb{R}^*$ that induces the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}$ and the order topology on $\mathbb{R}^*$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

The extended real line $\mathbb{R}^*$ is usually equipped with the order topoloy, which is generated by the basis $\mathscr{B}=\{(a,b):a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}\cup\{(a,\infty]:a\in\mathbb{R}\}\cup\{[-\infty,a):a\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

And I have seen some metrics on $\mathbb{R}^*$, which are usually defined through a bijection $\varphi$ from $\mathbb{R}^*$ to maybe a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$. For example, $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^*\rightarrow[-1,1]$ could be the bijection:
$\varphi(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{x}{1+|x|},& x\in\mathbb{R}\\
1,& x=\infty\\
-1,& x=-\infty\\
\end{cases}$

Then define the metric $d^*$ to be the function from $\mathbb{R}^*\times\mathbb{R}^*$ to $[0,\infty)$ that maps each pair $(x,y)$ to $|\varphi(x)-\varphi(y)|$.

However,the metric $d^*$ defined in this way does not coincide with the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}$, i.e., $d^*|_{\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}}\neq d_{standard}$.

So is there a metric on $\mathbb{R}^*$ that simultaneously induces the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}$ and induces the order topology on $\mathbb{R}^*$?

Comment: Closest you can get is probably a metric $d$ on $\mathbb{R}^*$ such that $d|_{\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}}$ induces the standard metric topology on $\mathbb{R}$, however getting it to coincide with the standard metric is probably not possible

Comment: @Lorago; You're definitely right. Whenever d induces the order topology on $\mathbb{R}^*$, $d|_{\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}}$ also induces the standard metric topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order topology on $\mathbb{R}^*$ is compact, so the metric would have to bounded. But the metric on $\mathbb{R}$ is unbounded, so I would say you can't.

Comment: you are amazing. Thanks.

Comment: @OSCAR You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose such a metric $d$ existed, and let $\{x_j\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ with $x_j\to\infty$ as $j\to\infty$. Then, as metrics are continuous,

$$d(\infty,0)=\lim_{j\to\infty}d(x_j,0)=\lim_{j\to\infty}\lvert x_j\rvert=\infty,$$

which is a contradiction.